# Which movie/tv started showing scenes after credit?

Tags: first-appearance, credits

Usually marvel movies have some scenes after credits. Which movie started it all?

Comment: Well technically probably the first movie made back in the late 1800's or early 1900's to have credits (which would be a question in itself), because closing credits weren't common until the 1970's, and before that all credits were shown before the first scene.  Perhaps this question should be retitled "Which movie/tv started showing scenes after the ending credits?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[The Muppet Movie (1979)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079588/) was the first movie with a post-credit scene according to [this Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_with_post-credits_scenes) which lists all films with post-credit scenes.

Answer (score 32):

The *very-first* end-credit scene was apparently from **The Silencers** movie which was released in the year 1966 based on this [article](https://www.bustle.com/p/when-did-post-credits-scenes-start-the-trends-history-is-filled-with-twists-turns-3235313)

> The first modern post-credits scene seems to be the tag at the end of The Silencers, a 1966 James Bond spoof starring Dean Martin, according to the site What's After the Credits? The scene in question parodied the familiar James Bond tradition of teasing a future installment, but rather than the simple text card of "James Bond Will Return" seen in the 007 films, The Silencers featured actual footage of Martin's Matt Helm lounging on a bed with several scantily-clad women while overlain text reads: "Coming up next: Matt Helm meets Lovely Kravezit in Murderer's Row." Helm himself then says, "Oh my God," and hides his head in his hands. 
> [*source with images of scene*](http://aftercredits.com/2011/12/silencers-the-1966/)

The end-credit scene which became popular and spawned various future end-credit scenes is from the **Muppet movie (1979)**

> It wasn't until 1979, after The Muppet Movie featured Animal telling the audience to "go home" after the credits finished rolling, that post-credits scenes began to appear somewhat regularly — and almost exclusively — in comedies. 
> [*source with images of scene*](http://aftercredits.com/2011/10/muppet-movie-the-1979/)

While the Muppet movie popularized the concept of "comedy" end-credit scenes which is just for relief and an extra addition to the movie's comedy, the end-credits of Marvel movies variety which *teases the upcoming movies* was introduced in the movie **Masters of the Universe (1987)**. But due to it's collections and general reception, it did not pick steam...

> After the credits roll in 1987's Masters of the Universe, the presumed-dead Skeletor rises from under water to proclaim that he'll be back, but the film's poor box office performance prevented that from ever happening. 
> [*source with images of scene*](http://aftercredits.com/2011/10/masters-of-the-universe-1987/)

## TLDR:

- The Silencers introduced end-credits
- The Muppets movie popularized it and introduced the "comedy" end-credits which has no significance to the plot or tease the other movies
- Masters of the Universe introduced the "tease-hook for other movies" end-credits...

Comment: Edit Suggestion.  I don't think it's someone lovely named  "Kravezit"  I think it's someone named "Lovey Kravezit", a spoof on the typical Bond girl names

Comment: I had added based on the article content but you're right... It does say lovey in the image source... Edit away... :)

Comment: The tease for non-comedic movie sequels was present at least vestigially as far back as 1980's *Flash Gordon*, where "The final frame shows Ming's ring being picked up by the hand of an unseen person. Ming's evil laugh echoes as the ending credits roll. Following the credits, the text "The End" is shown on the screen before a question mark (?) is appended." (Description from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Gordon_(film)#Plot).) The modern way would be for the ring to be picked up after the credits, too, but the elements are all there.

Comment: This answer should be copy-pasted to the duplicate question by the answerer.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Don't worry. The moderators can (and will) just merge it over.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Pretty slick, slick. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The Muppet Movie (1979) is obviously the first traceable true post credit scene instance but the older is 1963 with the James Bond film From Russia with Love, which was the first Bond film to show the ubiquitous "James Bond will return in..." at the end of the credits.
(Source :[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-credits_scene))

Answer (score 2):

As for TV:

Several episodes of Monty Python's Flying Circus (1969–1974) have scenes after the ending credits.  For example, [The Money Programme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Monty_Python%27s_Flying_Circus_episodes#3._The_Money_Programme) (first aired 1972-11-02) has ending titles, then "Six more minutes of Monty Python's Flying Circus", followed by the [Argument Clinic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_Clinic) sketch.  The episode ends after an announcement of "One more minute of Monty Python's Flying Circus".

In the episode [Michael Ellis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Monty_Python%27s_Flying_Circus_episodes#2._Michael_Ellis), first aired 1974-11-07, the ending credits immediately follow the opening credits, which means that essentially the *entire episode* is after the ending credits.  The episode ends abruptly after a shop assistant in the "Different endings" sketch asks *Well, how about a sudden ending?*.